# Stacking table/matrix visualizations in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, visualization

[image: picture of three graphs for reference]

I currently have three different summary tables using the table visualization tool in power BI. I want to "stack" or combine these visualizations so that these tables can be readily downloaded all together at the same time. What's the best way to do so?

I've looked up how to combine them, but nothing has come up. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the tables in Power Query using [Table.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-combine) or GUI [Apppend Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/append-queries)

[image]

You can also do this in DAX with [UNION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/union-function-dax), but it's better to do it earlier.

Comment: Do I have to create the tables using DAX first? I'm currently using Power BI's table visualization tool to generate these tables.

Comment: You should create the new table in the Power BI Query Editor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-query-overview